# Block direct access to url and allowing access by system only

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis-6

I want to block access to a url from everything except for iis usr that requests the image.

So I have: `www.myurl.com/somedirectory/myfile.ashx`

I want only my requests from code behind to be able to access this file not users/bots/non-clients who can manually visit the file by going to the url.

Need to take into account that servers are load-balanced I am unsure if this will cause an issue.

How would I go about doing this.

Requested serverside:

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
httpRequest.Method = "GET";
httpRequest.UserAgent = "MobileQ.NET";
httpRequest.ContentType = "image/png";
response = httpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: Do you reqest the file on server side or does the client browser who access your page request the file?

Comment: The image is requested server side, but takes input from query strings. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in your `myfile.ashx` if the request is from `localhost`:

```
string client = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if(client == "localhost" || client == "127.0.0.1" || client == "::1")
    //DoWork
else
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    return;
}
```

Comment: This would be an issue if our servers are load balanced right?

Comment: I am going to do ["SERVER_NAMES"] this should resolve situation will let you know if this works.

Comment: If each server only went to itself (rather than out the load-balancer and back in) then their being load-balanced won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

IIS7 has request filtering built in which could help if you are using that version or up of course

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering

Comment: Thanks sorry we are currently in still in the ice age using iis 6. Thanks for the tip though!